# STS tool suite keeps hanging

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Fairly new install of STS version 4.0.1.RELEASE (build 201810300749) in Windows 10 keeps hanging. It always hangs for a few seconds on saves and content assist activations among other things. Every few hours or so, it will hang completely where it has to be killed.

This has happened on all STS installations over several jobs and projects, ranging from core i7s with 32 GB RAM to i5 with 16GB RAM (almost unusable).

I have increased the memory in the ini file. I also didn't install any plug-ins except m2e-wtp (Maven Integration for WTP).

We really need another option other than using Eclipse. Eclipse has become so slow after version 4.5.

The following is a stack dump of when it hangs. The main thread is hung on a FileOutputStream write call.

Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode):

```
"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-89" #1339 daemon prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x0000000020395800 nid=0x34ac waiting on condition [0x0000000055afe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000db9b7918> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
        ...

"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-46" #1334 daemon prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x0000000020395000 nid=0x2138 waiting on condition [0x00000000555fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000d692e9d0> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
        ...

"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-117" #1333 daemon prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x000000002038f800 nid=0x27d0 waiting on condition [0x00000000554fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000d9d35e40> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
        ...

"Worker-55" #1206 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000295d1800 nid=0x3718 in Object.wait() [0x0000000047eff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:200)
        - locked <0x00000000807dc088> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:58)

"Worker-53: Reading saved version of file for quick diff" #1106 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000295cf800 nid=0xd70 in Object.wait() [0x000000007b09e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:316)
        - locked <0x000000009988ae00> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.lockDocument(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.readDocument(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.access$0(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider$ReadJob.run(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

"Worker-52" #1093 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021272800 nid=0x19ec in Object.wait() [0x000000007a39f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:200)
        - locked <0x00000000807dc088> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:58)

"org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" #1084 daemon prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x0000000021264000 nid=0x170c waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000079a9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$CompilationUnitAnnotationModel.internalBeginReporting(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:609)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000000f05c2e48> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$CompilationUnitAnnotationModel.beginReportingSequence(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:210)

"Worker-47: Updating workspace" #1061 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021267000 nid=0x1408 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000007829e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageConsumer.consume(StreamMessageConsumer.java:66)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000000827235b8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.lambda$1(LanguageServerWrapper.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper$$Lambda$365/1111358623.consume(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.notify(RemoteEndpoint.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.EndpointProxy.invoke(EndpointProxy.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.didChangeWatchedFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.ResourceListener.sendFileEvents(ResourceListener.java:61)
        at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.ResourceListener.resourceChanged(ResourceListener.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2305)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$NotifyJob.run(NotificationManager.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

"Scheduler-185640897" #372 prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x0000000023191800 nid=0x2710 waiting on condition [0x000000004b4fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000091d28eb8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

"pool-2-thread-1" #32 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002010e800 nid=0x7bc in Object.wait() [0x0000000029f8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:316)
        - locked <0x000000009988ae00> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2240)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2287)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2314)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.diagnostics.LSPDiagnosticsToMarkers.accept(LSPDiagnosticsToMarkers.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageClientImpl.publishDiagnostics(LanguageClientImpl.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint$$Lambda$368/109209866.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.notify(GenericEndpoint.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleNotification(RemoteEndpoint.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.lambda$1(LanguageServerWrapper.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper$$Lambda$365/1111358623.consume(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:99)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"main" #1 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002e62800 nid=0x24c0 runnable [0x0000000002c79000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        - locked <0x00000000826bfed8> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageConsumer.consume(StreamMessageConsumer.java:69)
        - locked <0x00000000827235b8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.lambda$1(LanguageServerWrapper.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper$$Lambda$365/1111358623.consume(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.notify(RemoteEndpoint.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.EndpointProxy.invoke(EndpointProxy.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.didChange(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.DocumentContentSynchronizer.lambda$1(DocumentContentSynchronizer.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.DocumentContentSynchronizer$$Lambda$550/1149213193.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAccept(CompletableFuture.java:656)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:669)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:1997)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.DocumentContentSynchronizer.documentChanged(DocumentContentSynchronizer.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged2(AbstractDocument.java:747)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:716)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.fireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1105)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument.replace(SynchronizableDocument.java:176)
        - locked <0x00000000f05c2e48> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1123)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument.replace(SynchronizableDocument.java:164)
        - locked <0x00000000f05c2e48> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.text.edits.DeleteEdit.performDocumentUpdating(DeleteEdit.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit.traverseDocumentUpdating(TextEdit.java:916)
        at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit.traverseDocumentUpdating(TextEdit.java:909)
        at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditProcessor.executeDo(TextEditProcessor.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit.dispatchPerformEdits(TextEdit.java:738)
        at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditProcessor.performEdits(TextEditProcessor.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.performEdits(TextChange.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextFileChange.access$0(TextFileChange.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextFileChange$1.run(TextFileChange.java:272)
        - locked <0x00000000dd8074b8> (a org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.Lock)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.UISynchronizationContext.run(UISynchronizationContext.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.execute(TextFileBufferManager.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextFileChange.performEdits(TextFileChange.java:284)
        - locked <0x00000000dd8074b8> (a org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.Lock)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.perform(TextChange.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring$CleanUpChange.perform(CleanUpRefactoring.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2319)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpPostSaveListener.saved(CleanUpPostSaveListener.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$5.run(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1639)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.notifyPostSaveListeners(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1633)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.commitWorkingCopy(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1413)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$4.execute(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1491)
        at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider$DocumentProviderOperation.run(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation.execute(WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.lambda$0(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$$Lambda$547/594574685.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2319)
        at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:131)
        - locked <0x00000000dd781d18> (a org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.executeOperation(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.saveDocument(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:764)
        at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.performSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:5006)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.performSave(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1275)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSave(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1329)
        - locked <0x00000000f04e67a8> (a org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit)
        at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$TextEditorSavable.doSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:7114)
        at org.eclipse.ui.Saveable.doSave(Saveable.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.doSaveModel(SaveableHelper.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.lambda$1(SaveableHelper.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$$Lambda$630/2050761537.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.lambda$3(SaveableHelper.java:274)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$$Lambda$631/1893069426.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:356)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.lambda$3(WorkbenchWindow.java:2254)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$$Lambda$632/969207075.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2252)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.saveModels(SaveableHelper.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.savePart(SaveableHelper.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveSaveable(WorkbenchPage.java:3957)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3971)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SaveHandler.execute(SaveHandler.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:651)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:441)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$2(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1193)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1054)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1064)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1106)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1102)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1489)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4888)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4768)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4784)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2309)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3559)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$19/623224248.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)
```

Comment: not sure yet exactly what the root cause for this freezes is, but can you try to disable the language servers that you have installed in your STS4 installation in the preferences? It would be quite interesting to see if that improves the behavior or not. Can you try that?

Comment: I disabled the language servers as well as theming and the IDE seems much more usable now. Hopefully this was the issue, time will tell. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had an STS install that worked well for me. No idea why, I've heard others say the same thing and others have no issues at all.  I use eclipse's STS plugin since it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Here in 2022 still the same